# Reading Python Request to file

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using Requests Library to make RESTapi request.  I can successfully do a get and the receive the correct response back from the Server. I am trying to save the response from the GET to a file so that I can manipulate the data.

I don't get an error but nothing is written to the file:

```
def download_file(url, cafile, user1, pass1, local_filename):
    # NOTE the stream=True parameter
    r = requests.get(url, 
                     stream=True,
                     auth=(user1, pass1), 
                     verify=cafile,
                     headers={'content-type':'application/xml'}
                    )
    lines = r.iter_lines()
    first_line = next(lines)
    for line in lines:
        with open(local_filename, 'w')as g:
            g.write((line)+ '/')
    return (local_filename)
```

Comment: @austin: Consider removing fluff while you are at it: [Do not use signature, taglines, or greetings](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior).

Comment: Is that possible that lines is one-element array? Then your loop doesn't run at all

Answer (score 2):

You keep overwriting by opening the file in the loop,  open outside the loop once:

```
  with open(local_filename, 'w')cas g:
          for line in lines:
```

`'w'` opens a file for writing and will truncate the file so you would only ever get a single line of data in your file.
You could open in the loop with `a` for appending but it makes more sense to open the file once outside the loop.

I would also print `first_line` and each line in your loop to verify exactly what is being returned.

Answer (score 0):

Simply save the content of the response:

```
def download_file(url, cafile, user1, pass1, local_filename): # NOTE the stream=True
    parameter r = requests.get(url, stream=True, auth=(user1, pass1), verify=cafile,
            headers={'content-type':'application/xml'})
    with open(local_filename, 'w') as  g: 
        g.write(r.text)
    return (local_filename)
```